# Retrieving drag location on moving GridView

Tags: android, gridview, drag, ontouchlistener

My question is relatively simple.

**Backstory**

I utilize an onDragListener to detect the current touch location of a user.
This onDragListener is registered to a GridView which scrolls automatically while the user is touching.

**Issue**

The ultimate problem is that if the user stops moving their finger (and holds it completely stationary) there will be no location events monitored, triggered, etc.

Any input on possible solutions would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setOnTouchListener method and set a OnTouchListener with onTouch method in it, and make sure onTouch method always return false.then you record DragEvent in onDragListener when location change. and use the recorded DragEvent in onTouch method to do whatever you want.onTouch method will continuously trigger as long as the finger is down, since the location of drag is not changing, using the latest recorded DragEvent will serve you well.